# Is the given function Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n}, & \text{$\frac{1}{n+1}<x\le \frac{1}{n} $ } \\ 0, & \text{$x=0$} \end{cases}$

I have just learned Supremum and Infimum but dont know how to apply to this question

Comment: Observe that the set of points where this function is discontinuous is a sequence $1/2,1/3,1/4,...$ That can be covered by a sequence of intervals of length $1/2^n,1/2^{n+1},...$ with total length arbitrarily small. Therefore, by [Lebesgue's criterion for integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) it will be integrable.

Comment: If you are aware of Lebesgue's theorem on Riemann integrability, then notice $f$ is continuous every where bot a long the sequence $\{\tfrac1n\}$ which is a set of Measure $)$. Since your function is bounded, $f$ in Riemann integrable. If you are not versed on such matters, you can still show, using Darboux sums that your function is indeed integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof only using basic concepts on Riemann integrability (upper and lower sums and the characterization via partitions).

Observe that given tha partition $P_n=\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots,1/n,0\}$ (to be rigurous, one has to write it backwards) then $U(f,P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}$ and $L(f,P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$.

So given $\varepsilon>0$ you can find a $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0+1}<\varepsilon$. So for for the $n_0$-partition it holds that $$U(f,P_{n_0})-(f,P_{n_0})=\frac{1}{n_0+1}<\varepsilon$$ and this is squivalent to the Riemann-integrability of $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir!